# Add string to string in C with safe functions

Tags: c, string, strcat-s

I want to copy the a file name to a string and append ".cpt" to it. But I am unable to do this with safe functions (strcat_s). Error: "String is not null terminated!". And I did set '\0', how to fix this using safe functions?

```
size = strlen(locatie);
size++;
nieuw = (char*)malloc(size+4);
strcpy_s(nieuw, size, locatie);
nieuw[size] = '\0';
strcat_s(nieuw, 4, ".cpt"); // <-- crash
puts(nieuw);
```

Comment: what about `snprintf()`?

Comment: It appears your usage is incorrect. I have not used this function but as per [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d45bbxx4%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) code should be `strcat_s(nieuw, size, ".cpt");` as pointed in [shf301's response](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13092426/925381)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `size` parameter of the _s functions is the size of the destination buffer, not the source.  The error is because there is no null terminator in `nieuw` in the first for characters.  Try this:

```
size = strlen(locatie);
size++;
int nieuwSize = size + 4;
nieuw = (char*)malloc(nieuwSize );
strcpy_s(nieuw, nieuwSize, locatie);
nieuw[size] = '\0';
strcat_s(nieuw, nieuwSize, ".cpt"); // <-- crash
puts(nieuw);
```

Comment: +1, Though I have no experience with MS function just curious after reading [documentation of strcpy_s](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/td1esda9%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), isn't `nieuw[size] = '\0';` redundant?

Comment: Yes it is redundant.  `strcpy_s` will always null terminate the string.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe some standard solution?

```
const char * const SUFFIX = ".cpt";
size = strlen(locatie) + strlen(SUFFIX) + 1;  // +1 for NULL
nieuw = (char*)malloc(size);
snprintf(nieuw, size, "%s%s", locatie, SUFFIX);
```

Comment: much nicer. I can't believe how much harder it is to get `strcat_s` working right.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char old[] = "hello";
    size_t size = strlen(old) + 5;;
    char *new_name = (char*)malloc(size);
    new_name[size-1] = '\0';
    strcpy_s(new_name, size, old);
    strcat_s(new_name, size, ".cpp");
    printf("%s\n", new_name);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not

```
size = strlen(locatie);
size++;
nieuw = (char*)malloc(size+6);
strcpy_s(nieuw, size, locatie);
strcat_s(nieuw, 4, ".cpt");
puts(nieuw);
nieuw[size + 5] = '\0';
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out `asprintf`. It allows you to print to a string like printf

Comment: asprintf is not available for windows.

Answer (score 0):

```
size = strlen(locatie);
size++;
nieuw = (char*)malloc(size+4);
strcpy_s(nieuw, size, locatie);
nieuw[size] = '\0';
strcat_s(nieuw, size, ".cpt");
puts(nieuw)
```

;